No such module when archiving, Flutter iOS Companion App with watchOS target
I'm new to Flutter, I added a watch app target to my Flutter iOS app by choosing an existing app option.
Then I add pod to my watch app. Everything was working in debug mode on the device as well as the simulator.
But when I tried to make a build, It reproduced no such module found for Kingfisher, when I removed this then, It generated an error to the next pods install for the watch app.
Then I remove the watch app Target and build it. It succeeded.
thanks in advance.
Here is my pod file
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  platform :ios, '14.0'
 # pod 'Alamofire', '5.6.4'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFyber'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationInMobi'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationChartboost'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationIronSource'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationVungle'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
 # pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.13.1'

  
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'MyWatchApp' do
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!
    platform :watchos, '9.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '5.6.4'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '4.2'
    pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.13.1'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # Set iPhoneOS deployment target
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        end
  end
end

I tried removing pods and add these framework manually, but no luck.
I tried changing my watchapp target supported platform architecture to watchOS from default iPhoneOs. It works but after installing build to device the bridge between app and watch app was broken and I was not able to install watch app.
I also check podspec of each pods installed for compatibility (It was ok).
I also removed space between watch app target name.
I tried adding $(SRCROOT) in framework search path and make it recursive.
Also tried Excluded arm64 for release mode.

just ignore it and rebuild it

@RahulKushwaha, tried many time but each time it gives same error. This happen in case of archive(release mode), for debug mode it work fine

I have not faced an issues while creating archives .Do research more on this .
